# Type mismatch when using for each row in vba

Tags: vba

I'm trying to code a routine to add records from a range on the worksheet SR to a listbox on a form. I want the record in the listbox to be made up of the values from a few cells in each row.

I'm getting a type mismatch on the ResultString line. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm not seeing how what I've written is different from the usual suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

```
With SR
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Row As Range
Dim ResultString As String

Set Rng = Range("A2:AC" & LastRow)

For Each Row In Rng.Rows
    With SR
        ResultString = .Cells(Row, 1).Value & " - " & .Cells(Row, 2).Value & " - " & .Cells(Row, 3).Value & " - " & .Cells(Row, 9).Value & " - " & .Cells(Row, 25).Value
    End With
    Me.lstResults.AddItem ResultString
Next Row
```

Comment: In `.Cells(Row, 1)` you would need a numerical index rather than a range object (which is what `Row` is). Perhaps you mean `Row.Cells(1)` although in that case the `With` construct is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you a different approach:

```
Dim SR As Worksheet
Set SR = ActiveSheet

Dim LastRow As Long
With SR
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Me.lstResults
    .ColumnCount = 25
    .ColumnWidths = "20;20;20;0;0;0;0;0;20;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;20" ' adjust it to suit your needs
    .List = SR.Range("A2:AC" & LastRow).Value
End With
```

this way you don't need to iterate every row and join relevant columns content while filling the listbox in one shot with ALL range values and have relevant columns visible only

this way you loose the "-" delimiter but may be yo can get around it

Comment: Thanks! I like this approach as it'll organise my listbox much more neatly